# Comparing lines in two files and print only missing line

Tags: python

I have two files 1.0.txt and Master.txt and I need the list that has all the commits in 1.0.txt but missing in Master.txt

Commit example:

> 19175c1 Correct the logic by Jacob · 2 days ago 8.4.0.109

I need to compare only the message

> Correct the logic

and if this message is NOT in the master.txt then print it

```
import json

count = 0
with open("1.0.txt") as release, open("Master.txt") as master:
    for message in release:
        for line in master:
            splitting_line = message[8:].split(' by', 1)
            if not splitting_line[0] in line:
                count += 1
                print(f"{count}. {line}")
```

but this one is printing all the lines without comparison

Comment: The `for line in master:` loop consumes the master file on the first iteration of the `release` loop and leaves it at end-of-file for each subsequent iteration. You can do `master.seek(0)` at the end of the `release` loop. But note that your method could be very slow depending on the lengths of the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .rfind() to find the last instance of a substring in a string, so you can change your splitting_line assignment to this: `splitting_line = message[8:message.rfind(" by ")]`, this'll make your program a little better at saving memory and accounts for if you use the word "by" in your commit.

I struggled to recreate your issue, but there are a few other ways to look for if things are and aren't in strings. One way is with a string's .find() method. If it can't find any example of the substring, it'll return -1. So this could work:

```
if line.find(splitting_line) == -1:
```

If not, you could always use regex (regular expression), which is great for string searching in general. Start by importing the search function from the re module like this `from re import search`, then you simply use the splitting_line as the first parameter and line as the second, like the following:

```
if not search(splitting_line,line):
```

Regex is very powerful and you can even use this to skip around creating a new splitting_line variable by creating your own regex expression.